# Pandas - key error - not recognizing column name from csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am picking up the most recent csv file in a folder as shown below, and then converting into a DataFrame 'ES_VX_comb_LL_15M'.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

filename2 = max(glob.iglob(r"C:\Users\cost9\OneDrive\Documents\PYTHON\Daily Tasks\Pairs Trading\ES_VX\CSV\15M\Beta\*.csv"))
f6 = open(filename2)
ES_VX_comb_LL_15M = pd.read_csv(f6)
ES_VX_comb_LL_15M['Close_ES'] = ES_VX_comb_LL_15M[pd.to_numeric(ES_VX_comb_LL_15M['Close_ES'])]

ES_VX_comb_LL_15M = ES_VX_comb_LL_15M[np.isfinite(ES_VX_comb_LL_15M['Close_ES1'])]

path_to_csv = r'C:\Users\cost9\OneDrive\Documents\PYTHON\Daily Tasks\Pairs Trading\ES_VX\CSV\15M\Lead_Lag\ES_VX_comb_LL_15M_.csv'    
ES_VX_comb_LL_15M.to_csv(path_or_buf = path_to_csv)
```

Unfortunately I get the error "KeyError: 'Close_ES'" referring to a column in the csv file. This error refers to the to_numeric line above.

Normally this isn't an issue and I'm not sure what the problem is - the CSV file looks like this:

```
    Ticker_x    Date    Close_ES
1   ES U7   3/14/2017 6:14  2360
2   ES U7   3/14/2017 6:29  2362.25
3   ES U7   3/14/2017 7:44  2361.25
4   ES U7   3/14/2017 7:59  2359.25
5   ES U7   3/14/2017 8:14  2357.25
6   ES U7   3/14/2017 8:29  2355
7   ES U7   3/14/2017 8:44  2353.75
8   ES U7   3/14/2017 8:59  2354.75
9   ES U7   3/14/2017 9:14  2354.5
10  ES U7   3/14/2017 9:29  2359.25
11  ES U7   3/14/2017 9:44  2358.5
12  ES U7   3/14/2017 9:59  2359
13  ES U7   3/14/2017 10:14 2355.5
14  ES U7   3/14/2017 10:29 2356
15  ES U7   3/14/2017 10:44 2356
```

So it looks like it's separating the columns/values correctly. Why is the 'Close_ES' column not being recognized?

Comment: What is the output of `ES_VX_comb_LL_15M.columns`?

Comment: @akilat90 i've updated the code - i try to shoot the output to a new csv file, however no csv file gets created because of the key error.

Comment: @ColeStarbuck: you didn't answer akilat90's question.  If you `print(ES_VX_comb_LL_15M.columns)`, it'll make it very easy to see whether the column names have been correctly separated and whether there might be extraneous whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the separator to `'\t'` since pandas uses `','` by default.

```
pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t')
```